# Architectural structure of elm modules with dependant models

Tags: architecture, elm

I am currently digging deeper into elm and stumbled over the following Problem:

- I have two modules, module Jedi and module Droids.
- Jedi is capable of storing Jedi's, Droids stores Droids.
- I integrated both modules in an Main module via the elm architecture approach.

Now someone told me that every droid is owned by a Jedi (dont know if thats true). So I want to add a select box to the droids module - so I can assign a Droid to a Jedi. 
The Jedi's available for assignment shall be taken from the Jedis Model.

My first thougt was: Oh nice, I just import the main module in the droids module and try to extract my jedis.
But that does not work, because of circularity in module dependencies.

Next I thought: I import the jedi model in the droids model and enhance my droids model with that - so I can get my jedis into the select box for the "droid-owners". But that does not work either. When I update the jedis list there are no effects in my droids module (that is logic, because the Messages generated by jedis are poppeled upwards to main. Main recognizes them and updates the main module. But the droids model will never recognise updates in the jedis module).

So I think I have to understand some more fundamentals on architectures in elm. I think I break the whole elm architecture.

Can anybody explain how this should be properly realised - I think that is a fundamental issue to understand before start developing larger Apps.

Here a screenshot. You can see the Models of those as a String below every component

[image: Screenshot]

Would appreciate some comments or hints or where to read more about... Thanks :-)

**UPDATE**

I have all three files in a gist:
https://gist.github.com/marschro/7584216d5bdfed077b26a9d32c5b5cf6

Comment: Can you share your code anywhere (eg Github)? By the sounds of it, you're making each module a little Elm application of its own, with its own update function, own model, own view, etc and using Main to combine them. The Elm Architecture actually recommends having *one* update function, *one* model, etc for your entire application. Breaking things into components is done by making functions that return Html/Html Msg, which you can use to build up the main view -- so Jedis and Droids wouldn't need to use *each other's* update functions, everything would be sharing the one.

Comment: I'd take a peek at @Fresheyeball 's workshop (0.17)... https://github.com/Fresheyeball/lambdaconf-2016-elm-workshop

It has this dependency thing you're looking for.

Comment: @RyanPlant Thanks for your comment. Yes that is what I do. I thought or understood the concept like this, that in fact every module has MUV. Breaking things in components in view functions seems to be problematic. Because functions are Model -> Html Msg. If I define such a function in a separate file the compiler asks me where "Model" is. As the model is defined in main, I would have to import the Main.Model. But that produces circularity. I can get rid of the compiler error by removing the type annotations. But that is not very elegant. Elm is perfect, but I have like knot in my brain on this

Comment: @marschro: You can define your types (Model and Msg) in a special file that you import both in your View file and in your Main file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Pass model.jedis to Droids.view from Main.view.  You will have to modify Droids.view to accept an additional argument of List Jedi.  Documentation on the core Elm functions can be confusing.  They all have a default signature i.e.

```
view : Model -> Html Msg
```

but that is just the most basic signature.  For this example modify it to be

```
view : List Jedi -> Model -> Html Msg
```

now you have the most up to date list of Jedis
As far as module references you can do

```
import Jedi exposing (Jedi)
```

from your Droid module

Comment: Good hint. Thanks. For my needs I re-architectured my App and currently use the approach which is suggested James Moore on http://courses.knowthen.com/